# Starting http-server on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup and access a simple Python http-server on an Amazon EC2 instance.
The server works locally under localhost:80, but I cannot get it to work on the EC2 instance.

I connected an elastic IP to the instance, and it at least works to access ssh on that IP.

I think the problem is that I'm setting the server_address for the HTTPServer incorrectly:
[Python HTTPServer documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer)
Since I really don't have a clue, at home I configured the router to forward HTTP requests to the computer's local IP, 192.168.1.xx

I thought that it might be a security group issue, so I added inbound HTTP with source 0.0.0.0/0 (which I thought should allow all incoming IPs) and sets port 80 without any option to change.

Additionally, I think that running the server script under sudo on port 80 is a potential security risk. Is there any way to forward the request under another port like 8080 instead of 80?

Comment: Python's HTTPServer probably doesn't drop privileges so it's not safe to run as root. What exactly is your setup? Are you trying to access a HTTPServer hosted on your computer from the EC2 instance?

Comment: What are you using as the server_address argument to HTTPServer? You should have something like nginx or apache infront of this service/web site if other people will be consuming it. Also, consider using a library like [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) It could make your life easier.

Answer (score 3):

From a security point of view it might be better to run your script behind a regular http server.

Here is a configuration for [NginX](http://nginx.org) that should get you started (puth this file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`):

```
upstream myscript  {
  server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80;
    location = / {
        proxy_pass  http://myscript;
    }
}
```

In this setting, you run your script on port 8080 (use `server_address = ('localhost', 8080)` to configure your `HTTPServer` in your python script).

So when a query hits nginx on port 80 it forwards it to localhost port 8080 where your script takes in charge.

Answer (score 3):

For the security group, you can create a rule that allows port 8080 (Do "Custome TCP Rule", then put 8080 for the port range).

It sounds likely that your HTTPServer is binding to loopback. I would set the address to 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces), set the port to 8080, and open 8080 on your security group.